# asDict method in pyparsing overrides previous key

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

I have a contrived example of a problem that I am facing:

```
import pyparsing as pp

fname = pp.OneOrMore( pp.Word("Max") ).setResultsName("fname")
mname = pp.OneOrMore(s pp.Word("Joseph") ).setResultsName("mname")
lname = pp.OneOrMore( pp.Word("Andrews") ).setResultsName("lname")
another_mname = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("Miller")).setResultsName("mname")

full = fname + mname + lname + another_mname

output = full.parseString("Max Joseph Joseph Andrews Miller Miller").asDict()

# current output 
{'fname': ['Max'], 'lname': ['Andrews'], 'mname': ['Miller', 'Miller']}
```

It is obvious why the output is the way it is. However, I would like also to collect 'Joseph' as another value. e.g.

```
# desired output
{'fname': ['Max'], 'lname': ['Andrews'], 'mname': ['Joseph', 'Joseph', 'Miller', 'Miller']}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not `'mname': ['Joseph', 'Joseph', 'Miller', 'Miller']`?

Comment: Edited. My bad. yeah i needed ['Joseph', 'Joseph', 'Miller', 'Miller']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not work because you set the name of the results to be same.
This cause the `"mname"` entry associated to `mname` in the resulting `dict()` to be replaced by the `"mname"` entry associated to `another_mname`.

One way workaround to this would be to collect the names into two separate results and join those afterwards:

```py
import pyparsing as pp

fname = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("Max"))("fname")
mname = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("Joseph"))("mname")
lname = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("Andrews"))("lname")
another_mname = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("Miller"))("mname2")

full = fname + mname + lname + another_mname

output = full.parseString("Max Joseph Joseph Andrews Miller Miller").asDict()
print(output)
# {'fname': ['Max'], 'mname': ['Joseph', 'Joseph'], 'lname': ['Andrews'], 'mname2': ['Miller', 'Miller']}

# clean-up dict
output['mname'] = output['mname'] + output['mname2']
del output['mname2']

print(output)
# {'fname': ['Max'], 'mname': ['Joseph', 'Joseph', 'Miller', 'Miller'], 'lname': ['Andrews']}
```

---

Note that you cannot simply define `mname` to be:

```py
mname = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("Joseph") | pp.Word("Miller"))("mname")
```

This would lead to a similar issue:

```py
import pyparsing as pp

fname = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("Max"))("fname")
mname = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("Joseph") | pp.Word("Miller"))("mname")
lname = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("Andrews"))("lname")

full = fname + mname + lname + mname

output = full.parseString("Max Joseph Joseph Andrews Miller Miller").asDict()
print(output)
# {'fname': ['Max'], 'mname': ['Miller', 'Miller'], 'lname': ['Andrews']}
```

but for a different reason: now the `mname` at the end of `full` is replacing the previous value of `mname`.

---

One could also automatize this, e.g.

```py
import pyparsing as pp

fname = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("Max"))("fname")
mname = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("Joseph"))("mname:0")
lname = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("Andrews"))("lname")
another_mname = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("Miller"))("mname:1")

full = fname + mname + lname + another_mname

output = full.parseString("Max Max Joseph Joseph Andrews Miller Miller").asDict()
print(output)
# {'fname': ['Max', 'Max'], 'mname:0': ['Joseph', 'Joseph'], 'lname': ['Andrews'], 'mname:1': ['Miller', 'Miller']}


def quench(pp_dict, mapping=lambda k: k.split(':')[0]):
    result = {}
    to_remove = []
    for k, v in pp_dict.items():
        new_k = mapping(k)
        if k != new_k:
            if new_k not in result:
                result[new_k] = []
            result[new_k].extend(v)
        else:
            result[k] = v
    return result


print(quench(output))
# {'fname': ['Max', 'Max'], 'mname': ['Joseph', 'Joseph', 'Miller', 'Miller'], 'lname': ['Andrews']}
```

Or, even more mindlessly by preprocessing `full` by automatically  converting multiple `"mname"` instances to *numbered* ones (e.g. `"mname:0"`) to be quenched later.

---

## EDIT

(as pointed out by @PaulMcG)

This mechanism is implemented in `pyparsing` directly:

```py
import pyparsing as pp

fname = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("Max")).setResultsName("fname")
mname = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("Joseph")).setResultsName("mname", listAllMatches=True)
lname = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("Andrews")).setResultsName("lname")
another_mname = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("Miller")).setResultsName("mname", listAllMatches=True)

full = fname + mname + lname + another_mname

output = full.parseString("Max Joseph Joseph Andrews Miller Miller").asDict()
print(output)
# {'fname': ['Max'], 'mname': [['Joseph', 'Joseph'], ['Miller', 'Miller']], 'lname': ['Andrews']}
```

or even like this:

```py
import pyparsing as pp

fname = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("Max")).setResultsName("fname")
mname = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("Joseph") | pp.Word("Miller")).setResultsName("mname", listAllMatches=True)
lname = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("Andrews")).setResultsName("lname")

full = fname + mname + lname + mname

output = full.parseString("Max Joseph Joseph Andrews Miller Miller").asDict()
print(output)
# {'fname': ['Max'], 'mname': [['Joseph', 'Joseph'], ['Miller', 'Miller']], 'lname': ['Andrews']}
```

although the result is a `list` of `list`s and not a single flattened one.

Comment: `setResultsName` has an optional `listAllMatches` argument that will do this quenching at parse time if set to True. But the concept is largely as you have described.